# Read value provider argument in dataflow template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have cloud function that launches dataflow template when new file is loaded and passes route on GS to that file. I have to read that as a value provider and pass it in pipeline like this.

```
 class DataFlowOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--input')

dataflow_options = PipelineOptions().view_as(DataFlowOptions)

pipeline = apache_beam.Pipeline(options = dataflow_options)

(pipeline
    | fileio.MatchFiles(dataflow_options.input)
    | fileio.ReadMatches()
    | apache_beam.FlatMap(lambda f: csv.DictReader(io.TextIOWrapper(f.open())))
    # ...
)
```

But I get this error when template starts: AttributeError("'RuntimeValueProvider' object has no attribute 'strip'")

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to [the documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.24.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#apache_beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles) the MatchFiles method does not seem to take ValueProvider arguments, only strings. A workaround would be to use the [MatchAll](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.24.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#apache_beam.io.fileio.MatchAll) method instead since it uses a PCollection as input. By creating an [Impulse transform](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.24.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html?highlight=impulse#apache_beam.transforms.core.Impulse) outputting to a [custom DoFn that uses your ValueProvider](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-functions) you can output a PCollection containing your ValueProvider's value as a single element, which will be read by MatchAll.